# Switch layout android using Intent and Models Getter and Setters

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to view the "enderecos" values in another layout, I'm parsing a json and using volley adapter, I was following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial and trying to adapt the onClick function used in that. But when I switch to the new layout it shows me nothing

What am I missing? I'm very new to android development.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private ListView lstView;

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<ClientesModel> arrNews ;
    private ArrayList<ClientesContatosModel> arrContatos ;
    private LayoutInflater lf;
    private VolleyAdapter va;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lf = LayoutInflater.from(this);


        arrNews = new ArrayList<ClientesModel>();
        arrContatos = new ArrayList<ClientesContatosModel>();
        va = new VolleyAdapter();

        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        lstView.setAdapter(va);
        mRequestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://192.168.1.17/mais-api/api/clientes/index.php";
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please Wait...","Please Wait...");







        JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {




            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
                try {
                    parseJson(response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                va.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pd.dismiss();
                ;            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                error.printStackTrace();
                pd.hide();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", "rm@.com.br");
                params.put("senha", "xxx");


                return params;
            }


        };
        mRequestQueue.add(jr);



    }



    private void parseJson(JSONObject json) throws JSONException{
        try{



            JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray("dados");

            for(int i=0;i<dados.length();i++) {

                JSONObject item = dados.getJSONObject(i);


                ClientesModel mClientesModel = new ClientesModel();
                ClientesContatosModel mClientesContatoModel = new ClientesContatosModel();

                /* cadastra os dados necessários no objeto no modelo */
                mClientesModel.setId(item.optInt("id"));
                mClientesModel.setNome(item.optString("nome"));
                mClientesModel.setTipo_pessoa(item.optString("tipo_pessoa"));
                mClientesModel.setInformacoes_adicionais(item.optString("informacoes_adicionais"));
                mClientesModel.setCpf(item.optString("cpf"));
                mClientesModel.setCnpj(item.optString("cnpj"));
                JSONArray contatos = item.getJSONArray("enderecos");
                for(int j=0;j<contatos.length();j++){
                    JSONObject data = contatos.getJSONObject(j);

                    mClientesContatoModel.setNome(data.optString("endereco"));

                }

                arrNews.add(mClientesModel);
                arrContatos.add(mClientesContatoModel);
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }






   public class VolleyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrNews.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return arrNews.get(i);

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            final ViewHolder vh ;
            if(view == null){
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                view = lf.inflate(R.layout.row_listview,null);
                vh.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                vh.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
                vh.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                vh.tvContato = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);


                view.setTag(vh);
            }
            else{
                vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            ClientesModel nm = arrNews.get(i);
            vh.tvTitle.setText(nm.getNome());

            vh.tvDesc.setText(nm.getTipo_pessoa());


          final ClientesContatosModel nm2 = arrContatos.get(i);



           view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ContatosView.class);



                 in.putExtra("endereco", "nome");



                startActivity(in);

            }
        });



            return view;

        }






      public  class  ViewHolder{
            TextView tvTitle;
            TextView tvDesc;
            TextView tvDate;
            TextView tvContato;

        }

    }
}
```

ContatosView:

```
public class ContatosView extends MainActivity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contatos_view);

        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra("nome");


        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);


        lblName.setText(name);



    }


}
```

Comment: why do you need `setContentView(R.layout.contatos_view);`? Wrong

Comment: Please, post a log from LogCat.

Comment: I want to switch the layout when I click on an item in the listview

Comment: on which line you are getting `NullPointerException`

Comment: @WARpoluido if you want to switch layout then use `Intend`

Comment: @WARpoluido switch to a new activity instead

Comment: @Vishrant if I use another activity, how can I show only the "enderecos" values in that activity?

Comment: you can use `putExtra` to set `enderecos` values for new activity which you will open using `Intend`

Comment: @Vishrant ok I'll try

Comment: @Vishrant I've edited the question, can you enlighten me as to how to dislpay that values? thank you

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm using a new activity now, but how to set the new activity to show the "endereco" values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve that question like I was told to do, using Intent:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ClientesContatosModel md = arrContatos.get(i);


                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ContatosView.class);


                    in.putExtra("endereco",md.getNome());





                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });
```

ContatosView:

```
public class ContatosView extends MainActivity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contatos_view);

        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra("endereco");


        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);


        lblName.setText(name);



    }


}
```

Thank you for your help!